# Extending k-means clustering to include interactions between elements

Tags: optimization

I'm searching for the right literature on how to optimally divide a set into a fixed number of bins with pre-determined sizes where the contribution of each element to the objective depends on the other elements in the same bin.

For example, in a scheduling context, certain employees work better than others so that the total output of one worker includes both the individual worker's productivity **and** his/her added (subtracted) productivity due to the other members on the team. Suppose I want to create a fixed $K$ number of teams of size $P$ that maximizes overall productivity, or the one that creates teams with the greatest difference in productivity.

Another example from finance would be one where I want to group assets together to minimize variance. Since assets covary, grouping assets together depends both on the variance of each asset and its covariance with other assets.

I've considered several streams of literature that don't quite fit:

- Bin Packing - doesn't fit since I have a fixed number of bins
- Knapsack - again, fixed number of objects that I want to take, but with the added complexity that the value of an object is both its inherent value and the additional value it gains when taken with something else.
- $k$-means clustering - I think this is the closest, but the measures of distance does not depend on which other objects are in the same cluster, and also cluster sizes are not fixed.

Any suggestions on literature that is related if it is already out there or perhaps thoughts on ways to tackle the problem? If this is the wrong forum, is there a better place to ask this question?

Comment: Sounds like a straightforward combinatorial optimization problem. These are usually intractable to solve optimally but I have had success with genetic algorithms. It seems applicable here.

Comment: k-means minimizes *variance*. It would put people with similar "productivity" in the same team. No, this will not help you. You need to treat this as an **optimization problem**, formalize your objective, and then try the usual optimization strategies: greedy, evolutionary, particle swarm, exhaustive search (how many million people do you have?). It's not machine learning nor clustering.

Comment: Thank you both! Exhaustive search is no feasible, so I will explore the other 4 suggestions.